# Can I pull data from Hive into Splunk?

Tags: hive, splunk

I have data flowing into HDFS with a daily partitioned Hive table on top.  I want to alert if the daily counts are higher or lower than expected.

Currently I am using Splunk as my alerting tool and I wanted to know if I could pull data from Hive into Splunk.

Ideally I could run a Hive query from Splunk nightly, but if that is not possible that I would like to populate a Hive table that Splunk could pull in nightly.

Comment: Something like Hunk? http://www.informationweek.com/big-data/big-data-analytics/splunk-spawns-hunk-hadoop-tool/d/d-id/1110529?

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I thought Hunk was Splunk running on top of Hadoop, not Splunk pulling data from Hadoop.  Is Hunk both of these things?